# setting default culture. is it context specific ? (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, cultureinfo

I am curious about one thing. In `Application_AcquireRequestState` event of `global.asax` I am setting the default culture for the threads that will be created in future and for the current executing thread. this is the code used.

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo('some-CULTURE');
```

The reason for that is following. suppose thread has a culture of `fr-FR` (and it's not a default culture) and than you run a task inside that thread, the culture on that  thread that runs the task, will be different from thread it originated from . I don't want that to happen so that's why I am setting the default culture. This is all happening because CultureInfo is not being copied from thread to thread. so now suppose there are two concurrent request coming to my website. and I set default culture to suppose 'fr-FR' and then immediately by second request the default culture is set to 'en-US' (and system locale is something different) now if I create a thread inside a code that runs under first request will that threads culture be 'fr-FR' or 'en-US' ? I suppose that it will be 'en-US' because last time when default culture was set it was set to 'en-US'. Or will the threads created or used by the thread that set the default culture to 'fr-FR' have the culture 'fr-FR' and the threads created or used by the thread that set default culture 'en-US' will be 'en-US' ?